# An old sci fi book series about a supernatural family involving a sibling feud

Tags: story-identification, books

Do any of you remember a book series from 1990's (possibly) with 10-15 books about a supernatural family (not immortal) who have a sibling feud that leads to a war.

One scene takes place on a narrow one person bridge and the armies are waiting at each side.

The author also did the audiobook narration of the series.

Comment: Supernatural how?  Magic beings?  Psychic humans?  Fallen angels?  Eldritch abominations?  What was the setting?  Contemporary Earth, past Earth, generic fantasy world?  Was there more than one world?  Why did they feud?  How did they make war?

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like Roger Zelazny's 1970 [*Nine Princes in Amber*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Princes_in_Amber), in which mystical (able to walk between different realities, amazing healing powers over the long term, sometimes actual sorcerers), yet not immortal brothers and sisters feud for succession leading to war. There is a scene in a narrow bridge, pass, or stairs (to me a little reminiscent of the [battle of Thermopylae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Thermopylae)).

*Nine Princes in Amber* was the first of [a series of five books, followed by another series of five books about the next generation within the family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber)). [Zelazny recorded audiobook versions himself in 1990](http://brandonmelendez.com/audio-files-nine-princes-amber-roger-zelazny/), despite not being a professional voice actor.

*Nine Princes in Amber* (and its sequels) has been published many times, but here are some paperback covers:

[image: Nine Princes in Amber paperback cover]  [image: Nine Princes in Amber paperback cover]  [image: Nine Princes in Amber paperback cover]

[image: Nine Princes in Amber paperback cover]  [image: Nine Princes in Amber paperback cover]  [image: Nine Princes in Amber paperback cover]

Comment: I thought of this one, but discarded it because AFAICT Zelazny never did any audiobooks.

Comment: @DavidW Zelazny actually did narrate the Amber Chronicles in 1990. I listened to it on YouTube a few years back, I am looking for a link, and will edit. It was an interesting listen, because Zelazny was not a professional voice actor, but of course had the author's insights about the characters.

Comment: Interesting; I can't find any trace of that on ISFDb.

Comment: @DavidW Make an entry! :) Here's the estate's [information on the subject](http://www.roger-zelazny.com/veilfirst/zelazny_audio.php). You can still find [used recordings](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=22536391476&searchurl=pt%3Dbook%26pics%3Don%26sortby%3D17%26tn%3Dnine%2Bprinces%2Bin%2Bamber%26an%3Droger%2Bzelazny&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-title2) for sale. And [here's](https://www.youtube.com/@MubasharwattooHusah/videos) a YouTube link to the first five books read by him.

Comment: Interesting that I have a fondness for both of the Avon covers, but not the other ones (especially not the AvoNova cover, ick).  The earlier one matches the style of the covers of *Lord of Light* and *Creatures of Light and Darkness* and the latter one matches the Merlin/Ghostwheel *Amber* books.

Comment: (FWIW, the abebooks link points to a recording by Alessandro Juliani; that one _is_ listed in ISFDb.)

Comment: @DavidW Oh dang, whoops! Obs copied the wrong link in my search. :) I totes dig the very first cover (especially the heavy type face!)... don't especially enjoy the others… especially the one that looks like David Hasselhoff with an explosion behind him.